# Dynamic values for both userform and its optionbutton

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub select_random_Question()
    Dim varList As Variant, total_numbers As Long, str1 As String, str2 As String
        'Dim start_range As Long
        'Dim end_range As Long
        Set se = Sheets("se")
        se.Activate
        str1 = "Number of Questions to attempt the Quiz"
        str2 = "Note:Random Questions will be Displayed"
        total_numbers = InputBox(str1 & vbCrLf & str2)
        'start_range = InputBox("Please enter the starting range")
        'end_range = InputBox("Please enter the ending range")
        varList = Random_Numbers(total_numbers, 1, total_numbers)
        Set coll1 = New Collection
        se.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(total_numbers, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(varList)


        For j = 1 To total_numbers
            myNum = Sheets("se").Cells(j, 1).Value
            Dim optbtn As MSForms.UserForm
            Dim usrfm As MSForms.OptionButton
            'coll1.Add myNum
            'Debug.Print coll1(j)
            'MsgBox myNum

            If IsLoaded("UserForm" & myNum + 1) Then
                MsgBox "Yes"
            Else
                For x = 2 To 5
                    If Sheets("Answers").Cells(x, myNum).Value = "" Then
                        'Do Nothing
                    Else
                        z1 = Sheets("Answers").Cells(x, myNum).Value
                        For z2 = 1 To 4
                            Set usrfm = "UserForm" & myNum + 1                  'This is where im get stuck
                            Set optbtn = "OptionButton" & z2
                            'With usrfm
                                '.optbtn.Caption
                            'End With


                        Next z2

                    End If
                Next x
            End If
            Select Case myNum
                Case Is = 1: UserForm2.Show
                Case Is = 2: UserForm3.Show
                Case Is = 3: UserForm4.Show
                Case Is = 4: UserForm5.Show
                Case Is = 5: UserForm6.Show
                Case Is = 6: UserForm7.Show
                Case Is = 7: UserForm8.Show
                Case Is = 8: UserForm9.Show
                Case Is = 9: UserForm10.Show
                Case Is = 10: UserForm11.Show
                Case Is = 11: UserForm12.Show
                Case Is = 12: UserForm13.Show
                Case Is = 13: UserForm14.Show
                Case Is = 14: UserForm15.Show
                Case Is = 15: UserForm16.Show
                Case Is = 16: UserForm17.Show
                Case Is = 17: UserForm18.Show
                Case Is = 18: UserForm19.Show
                Case Is = 19: UserForm20.Show
                Case Is = 20: UserForm21.Show
                Case Is = 21: UserForm22.Show
                Case Is = 22: UserForm23.Show
                Case Is = 23: UserForm24.Show
                Case Is = 24: UserForm25.Show
                Case Is = 25: UserForm26.Show
                Case Is = 26: UserForm27.Show
                Case Is = 27: UserForm28.Show
                Case Is = 28: UserForm29.Show
            End Select
        Next j
```

End Sub

im using random function to get a random number,using that random number im selecting a userform..in that userform i have a question "Which state capital is patna",selecting relevant option and saving answer in "Answers" sheet,but before getting a userform im checking whether that userform answer is saved or empty..

I'am trying to get Userform1.Optionbutton1.caption dynamically . . i.e., "UserForm" & myNum to get userform1 and using for loop to iterate through optionbutton values. . how do i get that??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us code examples or anything that we can use to suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. please find the above code as asked.. i have written in comments where im get stucked.. kindly refer and suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

```
usrfm = "UserForm" & myNum + 1 & "." & "OptionButton" & z2 & "." & "Caption"
StringExecute usrfm

Sub StringExecute(s As String)
               Dim vbComp As Object
               Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
               vbComp.codemodule.AddFromString "Sub foo()" & vbCrLf & "aa" & "=" & s & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
               Application.Run vbComp.name & ".foo"
               ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub
```

In order to make userform and its optionbuttons dynamic, i tried saving Userform.optionbutton().caption(dynamically) in usrfm as a string and executed string value as vba code with the help of vbcompnents.add

Thanks..